# Read the content of a zip file as a StorageFile object without extracting?

Tags: c#, uwp, zip, storagefile

Still working on my slideshow project! Not too shabby, it now can read recursively a directory, display the files in sequence or random order, zoom in and out, respond to keyboard and mouse input.

I'm trying now to make it read the content of zip file without extracting it. As I am reading recursively the root directory given by a user as input, it stores all the files it encounteres as a list of StorageFile objects. I would like to be able to read the content of a zip file and add its files (that are images) to the list of StorageFile, and then eventually open and extract a single given file if it is the next in sequence or random order.

What I have found so far allows to extract the files on disk or to read the content of the zip file as a list of strings.

Am I clear on what I need? ANy idea how to do this?

Thanks! :)

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? What have you tried so far

Comment: I'm looking for a class that will provide me with the functionality of reading from a zip file without extracting it and to read each element of the content of a zip as a StorageFile.

Somehow, everything I can find, including the ZipArchive class allows to read the list of files in the archive and extract one of them. For space and performance reason, I don't want to extract the file, just read it as a stream.

Comment: Ohh! Got it! ZipArchiveEntry.Open Method!

WIll post code sample once it works!

Comment: How is it going now?

Comment: Not well! lol! I spend a whole day fiddling with this without success. Even MS's own code does not work (mind you they often have syntax errors in them...).

Right now I'm working on solving another issue, but will get back soon to this and will post code samples (that don't work...).

Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... got it!

First, to read a specific entry, use ZipArchiveEntry.GetEntry(entrytosearch);

Second, can't read a ZipArchiveEntry into a IRandomAccessStream, I don't know why... fiddled with it for a good while before deciding to read it in memory first. Since what I'm doing is read images to display on screen, it has limited memory management impact. However, beware of the size if you're reading something big. I would put a check on the .Length of the entry before reading it. However, for simplicty purposes, here is the updated code to read a specific ".jpg" entry of a zip file into a Image.Source.

Not elegant or sophisticated yet, but i hope it saves someone the time I spent fiddling with this!

```
public class ZipItem
{
    public StorageFile motherfile { get; set; }
    public ZipArchiveEntry motherentry { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ActualBytes { get; set; }
    public string CompressedBytes { get; set; }
}

public List<ZipItem> results;
public int i = 0;

private async void  nextimg_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Open the zip file. I previously stored all zip files and stored them in the "results" a list of ZipItems populated in another method
    Stream stream = await results[i].motherfile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();

    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
    {
        //look for the entry "i", which is my current slideshow position
        ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.GetEntry(results[i].motherentry.Name);

        //Open the entry as a stream
        Stream fileStream = entry.Open();

        //Before I read this in memory, I do check for entry.Length to make sure it's not too big. 
        //For simplicity purposes here, I jsut show the "Read it in memory" portion
        var memStream = new MemoryStream();
        await fileStream.CopyToAsync(memStream);
        //Reset the stream position to start
        memStream.Position = 0;

        //Create a BitmapImage from the memStream;
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = (int)ctlImage.Height;
        bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = (int)ctlImage.Width;

        //Set the source of the BitmapImage to the memory stream
        bitmapImage.SetSource(memStream.AsRandomAccessStream());

        //Set the Image.Source to the BitmapImage
        ctlImage.Source = bitmapImage;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got as far as opening zip files, reading their ZipArchiveEntry content and creating a list in memory of the ZipArchiveEntries. However where I'm stuck is on two things:

1) How to I re-open a ZipArchive and access a specific ZipArchiveEntry in my list?

2) How can I read that ZipArchiveEntry that is a .jpg image into an BitmapImage to display it into an Image.Source?

Here is a code sample, and it ain't working! lol!

```
    public class ZipItem
    {
        public StorageFile motherfile { get; set; }  //Source File
        public ZipArchiveEntry motherentry { get; set; }  /Compressed file within the source file
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ActualBytes { get; set; }
        public string CompressedBytes { get; set; }
    }

    public List<ZipItem> results;      //List of all ZipItems (all elements of a Zipfile, for manipulation purposes)
    public int numfiles = 0;   // Total number of files 
    public int i = 0;   //Pointer to the current element in the list (for slideshow purposes)


    private async void  nextimg_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Stream stream = await results[i].motherfile.OpenStreamForReadAsync(); //Create a stream... I know this is the wrong type (see error below)

        ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Update);  //Open the ZipArchive. This gives me an error telling me that "Update mode requires a stream with Read, Write and Seek permission.

        ZipArchiveEntry entry = results[i].motherentry; //This is where I'm stuck.... how do I tell it to open a specific entry in the zip file?

        using (var fileStream = entry.Open()) //How do I open it as an IRandomAccessStream?
        //using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = results[i].motherentry.Open());
        {

            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = (int)ctlImage.Height;
            bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = (int)ctlImage.Width;
            bitmapImage.SetSource(filestream); //I know I need a IRandomAccessStream
            ctlImage.Source = bitmapImage;   //Hopefully display the image... 

        }

    }
```